Density Functions and Probability Calculation
X and Y are independent $U(0, 1)$ random variables. In other words, we have the density functions: $f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and
$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$ Calculate $P(X + Y \geq 1.5)$.
I really don't know how to solve this and in the answers they did this, I don't need help solving this integral, I just wanna know how to get here: $\int_{0.5}^1\int_{1.5-y}^1\, dxdy$.

You don't need an integral. Draw the unit square.  The joint distribution is the same as picking a point uniformly at random in the center.  Now look at the region defined by the inequality and read off its area.

@lulu not sure I'm following

Draw the unit square with corners at $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$.  Which points $(x,y)$ in that square satisfy $x+y>1.5$?  If you draw the picture you should see that it's a region with easily computed area.

@lulu yes you are right, but what if this wasn't uniform distribution. I still kinda wanna understand the integrals. I thought we did somethign like this:  $P(X+Y\geq1.5) = P(X\geq1.5-Y) = 1 - P(X<1.5-Y) = 1-P(1.5-Y)$

Nothing like that is true.  As to the integral,  you should be able to set up the integral that gives the area of that region.  If you had a non uniform density for the joint distribution,  you'd just take the same integral but use the density as the integral instead of the constant 1.


I don't need help solving this integral, I just wanna know how to get here. $$\int_{0.5}^1\int_{1.5-y}^11\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y$$

The support is $\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq 1~,~ 0\leq y\leq 1\}$ and the condition is $\{(x,y):1.5-y\leq x\}$
The intersection of these is $\{(x,y): 1.5-y\leq x\leq 1~,~ 1.5-1\leq y\leq 1\}$
Hence the bounds for that integral.
